# A closed form for the sum $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma{(a k)}}{\Gamma{(b k)}}{\lambda}^{-k}$ where $0<a<b$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, closed-form

Let $b>a>0$. Consider the sum
$$F(\lambda):=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma{(a k)}}{\Gamma{(b k)}}{\lambda}^{-k}.$$

The asymptotic behavior of $F(\lambda)$
as $\lambda\to 0^{+}$ and as $\lambda \to+\infty$
are discussed here
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/445799/the-asymptotic-behavior-of-f-lambda-sum-k-0-infty-frac-gammaa-k/445855#445855

Is it possible to compute the sum $F(\lambda)$ or approximate it with some remainder term (that obviously depends on whether $\lambda$ is small or large) ?